# Import error no module in Django

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am importing a module named `python_contextual_test_manager` in forms.py as follows:

```
from python_contextual_test_manager.main_runner import main as main_runner
```

Both `python_contextual_test_manager.py` and `forms.py` are in the same directory but it shows me the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named python_contextual_test_manager
```

What to do?

Comment: you should show your file stru0cture, I don't see anything related with django from your description :

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a dot in front of the file name should get you sorted. Like this:
`from .python_contextual_test_manager.main_runner import main as main_runner`.

The dot specifies that you want to import from the same folder that the file is in. Another way is to make the path absolute to the project directory, for example if all of that exists inside a Django app called `app`, then you could also import
`from app.python_contextual_test_manager.main_runner import main as main_runner`.